# How to handle environmental variables in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying Indextank for search.

In the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  tankit 'rails_3_demo' do
    indexes :title
    indexes :content
  end
```

Problem with this is that dev/test/staging/prod environments are all using the same index. What's the right way to make sure the environments are using the right env index?

Thanks,

GEM: https://github.com/kidpollo/tanker

Comment: is this a plugin/gem? Can you link to the gem so we can see the docs?

Comment: @Bryce, here is the tanker: https://github.com/kidpollo/tanker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by "using the same index" you mean using the same IndexTank API endpoint.

I think what you need to do is set up different endpoints at IndexPoint for each environment and then setup an initializer in your rails stack to point to the appropriate environment's tank. Looks like you get 100k documents free at IndexTank so you shouldn't run into any pay barriers for this setup:

```
#initializer
tanks = {
 "development" => 'http://:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.api.indextank.com',
 "test" => 'http://:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.api.indextank.com',
  ...
}

YourAppName::Application.config.index_tank_url = tanks[Rails.env]
```